# How to typeset this equation?

Tags: math-mode, align, amsmath, mathtools

This equation from some math book,
[image: equation]

position 1 and position 2 is in the same column, I tried

```
\begin{align}
x_n&=\begin{aligned}[t]
       &\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^n = \binom{n}{0}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^01^n + 
       \binom{n}{1}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^11^{n-1}+\binom{n}{2}\left(\frac{1} 
       {n}\right)^21^{n-2}+\\
       &+\binom{n}{3}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^31^{n-3}+\cdots+\binom{n}{k}\left(\frac{1} 
       {n}\right)^k1^{n-k}+\cdots+\binom{n}{n}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^n1^0
     \end{aligned}\nonumber\\
&=\begin{aligned}[t]
    &1 + 1 + \frac{1}{2!}\left(1 - \frac{1}{n}\right) + \frac{1}{3!}\left(1 - \frac{1} 
    {n}\right)\left(1 - \frac{2}{n}\right) + \cdots\\
    &+ \frac{1}{k!}\left(1 - \frac{1}{n}\right)\cdots\left(1 - \frac{k-1} 
    {n}\right)+\cdots+\frac{1}{n!}\left(1 - \frac{1}{n}\right)\cdots\left(1-\frac{n-1} 
    {n}\right).
  \end{aligned}
\end{align}
```

but the result is not what I want.
[image: ugly result]

Comment: Is the only issue the numbering? And yes, remove the closing `+` on the first line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest you use a single `aligned[b]` environment inside an `equation` environment. That way, just one equation number will be produced. The `[b]` positioning specifier assures that this equation number will be placed on the bottom row.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{amsmath}    % for 'aligned' environment
\usepackage{mleftright} % see https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mleftright
\mleftright

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}[b]
x_n
&=\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^n \\
&= \binom{n}{0} \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^{\!0} 1^n + 
   \binom{n}{1} \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^{\!1} 1^{n-1}+
   \binom{n}{2} \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^{\!2} 1^{n-2} \\
&\quad+
   \binom{n}{3} \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^{\!3} 1^{n-3}+\dots+
   \binom{n}{k} \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^{\!k} 1^{n-k}+\dots+
   \binom{n}{n} \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^{\!n} 1^0 \\
&=1 + 1 + 
   \frac{1}{2!} \left(1 - \frac{1}{n}\right) + 
   \frac{1}{3!} \left(1 - \frac{1}{n}\right) 
                \left(1 - \frac{2}{n}\right) + \dotsb\\
&\quad+ 
   \frac{1}{k!} \left(1 - \frac{1}{n}  \right) \dotsb 
                \left(1 - \frac{k-1}{n}\right)+\dots+
   \frac{1}{n!} \left(1 - \frac{1}{n}  \right) \dotsb 
                \left(1 - \frac{n-1}{n}\right) .
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: To OP: Note also the extra line in this answer. It does not hide that extra step in the equation chain that was present in the book. (+1)

Comment: It worked, sir. I think the magic thing is the `\quad` before the plus sign. It makes the plus sign, 1 and ( exactly on a vertical line. BTW, is the `\!` before the exponent really necessary, or is it some rule in math typesetting?

Comment: @Lucas - The `\!` (negative thinspace) elements help draw the exponents closer to the parenthetical expressions.